# Is it worth using jQuery for simple animations and image galleries?

Tags: jquery

And what is jQuery most commonly used for? Animations, forms, image galleries, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery is worth it. Not only does it speed up development time, but there is also an active development community which is always a plus. The code may seem large, but if you run the min version of it (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js).

It's really not that big when you consider the functionality. Also when using jQuery, you also have access to the UI effects. (http://jqueryui.com/) These can come is quite handy.

Comment: Ya, thats what I figure.  I mean if jquery is used for common animation to basic features of image galleries, then its the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is a JavaScript library which makes pretty much everything easier.  It's not too large, and the syntax is rather easy to learn.  You can do animations, AJAX requests, DOM manipulation etc and yes you could create an image gallery or validate a form.  jQuery UI has some form elements you could use, and there are plugins available for jQuery, some of which might provide an image gallery template system.

I would highly recommend it for the uses in your question title.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. jQuery does help you do a lot more by writing less JavaScript code. Thus saving you time and many browser compatibility issues. But jQuery is a javascript library, which means that it’s going to be larger. You have to determine what you are going to do, if you can do something simple with javascript, it's always better. But if it saves you time, it's well worth it, and it gives you a lot more functionality and flexibility. I'd go with it for all but the smallest changes.